# How to fix "Can't find variable: item"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm building a simple image listing app with some extra features, one of which is a download image function.

However, I keep getting this "Can't find variable item" error. How do I fix this?

`item.image`

```js
// ...

downloadImage = () => {
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}breathtaking.jpg`

  FileSystem
    .downloadAsync(item.image, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri)
    })

  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(fileUri, 'photo')
}

// ...
```

```js
return (
// ...
 <Button
   icon='file-download'
   mode='contained'
   onPress={this.downloadImage}
   style={{ borderRadius: 0, width: '33.4%' }}
 />
// ...
);
```

***UPDATE***

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = "/* json */";
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: shuffle(responseJson.listings),
          dataBackup: responseJson.listings,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 15, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
        <Card elevation={1}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              alignItems: "flex-start"
            }}
          >                  

            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.toggleModal();
                      this.setState({
                        webViewurl: item.image
                      });
                    }}
                    onLongPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.image)}
                    activeColor="blue"
                  >
              <ImageBackground
                source={{ uri: item.image }}
                style={{ height: 216 }}
              >
                <IconButton
                  icon="favorite-border"
                  size={20}
                  color="#6200EE"
                  style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
                  onPress={this._savedAlert}
                />
              </ImageBackground>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is `item` defined somewhere else? Is it a member variable of the same `class`? Please provide more code or try to find out where `item` is (supposed to be) located.

Comment: `item` is fetched from a json file hosted on github

Comment: Then you need to provide it to `downloadImage` when it's called, or make it a member of class you are using? Sadly without seeing more of your code I cannot tell what would be the correct solution...

Comment: My code is udated. Does this helps?

Comment: The code you have provided does not really help to see where the problem exactly is. Please use https://codesandbox.io/s/ to build a working example so that it is possible to analyse the code and find the problem. Maybe by now you've found the problem yourself!?

Comment: I've managed to successfully download the image, but somehow it always downloads the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

You do not have declared the variable `item`

```js
// ...

downloadImage = () => {
  const item = {}
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}breathtaking.jpg`

  FileSystem
    .downloadAsync(item.image, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
    })

  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(fileUri, 'photo');
}

// ...
```

You can do something like this

Comment: This will only change the error message but not help because the issue is another where did you declare item.

Comment: `item` is fetched from a json file hosted on github

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'this' keyword:

```
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      this.item.image,
      fileUri
)
```

Comment: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.item.image')`

Answer (score -1):

The item variable wasn't declared. So you can't use it.
Should bind the item in renderItem function to your downLoadImage function like so:

```js
renderItem = (item) => {
  return(
    // some code
    <Button
      onPress={this.downLoadImage.bind(this, item)}
      // some props
    />
    // some code
  )
}

downloadImage = (item) => {

// do something with item
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it kinda works, but now it gives "expo possible unhandled promise rejection open failed: ENOENT no such file or directory"